# is there rest APIs to create an agreement using a predefined template in Docusign CLM?

Tags: docusignapi

I want to integrate a web portal with DocuSign CLM. I have few form fields and a template in DocuSign CLM.

I want to perform the below tasks from the portal:

1. Mapping fields value sent from portal to form fields in the template
2. Generate an agreement using the template
3. View the agreement
4. Send it for e-signature

I want to know all CLM rest APIs that will allow me to use this programmatically from the frontend by passing values from our portal to CLM.

I went through the below CLM rest API docs but it didn't help much.
(https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, open a case through DocuSign support center - https://support.docusign.com/  More information on CLM https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-and-SpringCM

Comment: This question is too broad and is a request for work to be done on behalf of the asker. There are lots of pages that Docusign provides and the asker ought to do more research before asking such a wide ranging question.

Answer (score 2):

according to my teammates at DocuSign, you have to process all of your XML before you send it so that it is compatible with the merge template you’re sending it to.

This documentation may be helpful to look further into your question: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/reference/tasks/documentxmlmergetasks/

Comment: Thanks, Gloriana Marin.
There's more question around it but I'll directly contact support for more help.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a question but rather a demand and is not in the spirit of the stackoverflow. I suggest that you either start doing research to better understand the space that you are working in or find a partner or engage with [Professional services](https://www.docusign.com/features-and-benefits/services-support)

Here are some links to get you started.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/reference/tasks/documentxmlmergetasks/

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/setup-authentication

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/clm-api/clm101/auth